# Where can I find IDs for Windows OLE/COM Interfaces?

Tags: winapi, com, ole

Is there any particular reference or standard way of locating interface IDs for OLE Automation/COM interfaces? For example, the ID for the IWebBrowser2 interface is `D30C1661-CDAF-11D0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E` as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.uii.csr.browser.web.iwebbrowser2.aspx). However, the only way I was even able to locate this was because I already had the GUID in this particular case. The use-case here is the function CoCreateInstance which takes:

```
HRESULT CoCreateInstance(
  _In_  REFCLSID  rclsid,
  _In_  LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter,
  _In_  DWORD     dwClsContext,
  _In_  REFIID    riid,
  _Out_ LPVOID    *ppv
);
```

per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx)

But as you can see on that page, there is no way to know what riid I need for a given OLE interface. I'm talking Win API interfaces here, not 3rd party. CLSID is also somewhat difficult to find but they can be found either in the registry, or with a function which gets it from the process ID I believe. I'm trying to figure out what my options are to use with COM/CoCreateInstance.

Comment: the *riid* is usual known really. if you use documented interface from sdk/wdk header files it defined as `MIDL_INTERFACE("rid") ISomeInterface` - so you can use `__uuidof(ISomeInterface)` or macro [`IID_PPV_ARGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330727(v=vs.85).aspx). about *rclsid* here really question. in documentation need search which `CLSID` implement `ISomeInterface` or research this yourself

Comment: The bottom of each interface's MSDN page will also show the GUID. If you don't even know which interface you want, then I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: Completely unclear, what you are asking. Make sure to read Don Box' [Essential COM](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201634465). That will put you in a position to ask a better question.

Comment: @andlabs do you have an example? I see no IDs at the bottom of the pages.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for book recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't generally look for IIDs nor CLSIDs, you look for interfaces.

The IID is just `IID_ISomeInterface` 99% of the time and if you are using the Microsoft toolchain you can use `__uuidof(ISomeInterface)`. Most of the CLSIDs and IIDs are stored in uuid.lib and MSDN will tell you the name of the .LIB if you need to link with something else.

Once you have found the interface you need you then have to figure out how to create/get a instance of this interface. Sometimes you call `CoCreateInstance` and sometimes you call `QueryInterface` or [`QueryService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678965(v=vs.85).aspx) on a another interface you already have an instance of.

If we take `IWebBrowser2` as an example, if you look at [its page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(v=vs.85).aspx) you see that you should call `CoCreateInstance` with `CLSID_InternetExplorer` as the CLSID. The RIID can be any interface implemented by `CLSID_InternetExplorer` and MSDN lists the inherited interfaces right there on the page:

> The IWebBrowser2 interface derives from IDispatch indirectly; that is, IWebBrowser2 derives from IWebBrowserApp, which in turn derives from IWebBrowser, which finally derives from IDispatch.

It might implement other interfaces but you generally create the "main" interface and `QueryInterface` for anything else.

Some other interface like `IShellFolder` and `IShellItem` can be created in many ways, both from existing shell objects and "creator" functions in shell32.dll.

If you don't even know which interface you are looking for then you can search the .idl files that are part of the SDK, they should contain the declaration of most of the documented interfaces in Windows.

You can call [`StringFromIID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688692) on an IID if you absolutely want to know what the GUID is but most of the time you don't care. On the other hand, if you are dealing with undocumented interfaces then a GUID might be all you have and you have to use [OleView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx), the registry and the internet to try to figure out what the name of interface is and what its declaration looks like.

Comment: If you're analysing malware you may need to identify the interfaces via the IDs